# JSON file as a database

Tags: json, database

Okay. I'm (relatively) new to programming, and I've been doing it for the past two years or so. I never got that far into back-end development, as I really hate having to host a database constantly on my laptop, and if I want it constantly being hosted I have to pay for it.

So, today a thought just kind of popped up in my head. Can't I just use JSON's key-pair values as a database? Like, create a users.json file, and in it have something like:

```
{
  "users" : {
    "<user-id>" : {
      "name":"User"
      "password":"password123"
    }
  }
}
```

Instead of hosting the database, you can just read the file and find the value you are looking for, and if you want to store new values, you can edit the file?

I know SQLite does something similar to this, but this can be a dependency-free way of making a database that can be easily used for beginner projects.

I still don't really understand why this isn't more widely used if it works. Maybe because of cybersecurity issues? Either way, I'd like these questions answered:

1. Would the JSON database idea actually work?
2. What would the benefits be of using a hosted database instead of this?
3. If I don't care about cybersecurity, would the JSON database be a viable option?

Comment: > Can't I just use JSON's key-pair values as a database? - you can, but why? usually you shouldn't care about how data is _stored_ in DB, but rather about the way how 1) data is presented back to you when you do requests, and 2) how requests themselves are structured. Taking this into consideration, it seems you're looking for embedded doc-oriented DB - and those do exist ([poloDB](https://github.com/PoloDB/PoloDB))

Comment: Not a new idea - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat-file_database

Comment: 1.  For toy projects, sure.  How long will it take to get the password for a user id when you have 8 billion users?  2.  Security.  JSON  is plain text and can be read by anyone visiting your website.  Quicker access.  The information is indexed for quick retrieval.  3.  That depends on how much of a toy your website is.

Comment: Thank you. I have an idea of making a library that creates an encrypted file as a database, and you can do requests to it, therefore making a server-free database.

Comment: I'd like to note that you should never store passwords directly; store the hash, hash algorithm, and salt used. That way if your database gets pwned, your users passwords will still be relatively safe

Answer (score 0):

**Would the JSON database idea actually work?**

Yes, assuming a read-only setup from a user's perspective. It's effectively just using a configuration file and calling it a database.

**What would the benefits be of using a hosted database instead of this?**

Note, these are written as disadvantages of your approach:

- Reading

  - a user (frontend) has to read the whole JSON file and process it to get a single entry (fine when its 10 rows, what if it's 1,000,000+)
  - you'd have to roll your own indexing if you wanted to avoid having to scan through huge lists of data
- Writing

  - any changes to the configuration require the entire file to be rewritten (could mitigate by splitting 'tables' into separate files)
  - any changes must be done by the website owner (i.e. you)
- Security

  - no authentication/authorization means *all* users can read *all* the data

**If I don't care about cybersecurity, would the JSON database be a viable option?**

Sure, if you are the admin and aren't affected by the disadvantages above.